# How to find out the non printable character using unix vi command

Tags: unix

How to find the following non printable character in vi editer ^Q . press v then Q is not working. But its working for control then C .Can any one help to find out this special character. I want to replace ^Q with Q.

Answer (score 0):

Control/Q is ASCII `XON` (transmission on), normally used as part of your terminal's [*flow control*](http://www.modemhelp.net/faqs/flow.shtml).  You can usually enter it in `vi` by prefixing that with a control/V.

If you type `stty -a` on the command-line, that shows the characters which are assigned to these special functions.  For example:

```
> stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

While the [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) manual is terse, it gives some information.